# Prevent subdomain to use main domain's htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have many specific 301 redirection from main-domain to subdomain via htaccess. Old site will be moved to the subdomain (from main) while new site on the main. I like to preserve the SEO of the old site. Thus 301 link from the new site to the old site. (Assuming the 301 link does not exist on the new site).

Problem is the subdomain is accessing the main-domain's htaccess. Thus causing a redirect loop.

Some solution in mind.

1. Prevent sub-domain to access the main's htaccess
2. Exiting the htaccess if sub-domain address detected in main's htaccess
3. Make individual htaccess exclusive to self.

Have tried. [L]. [END]. [NC]

This is the subdomain htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /changeemail https://somethingsomething
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}       baiduspider|facebookexternalhit|twitterbot|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora\ link\ preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://service.prerender.io/http://%{HTTP_HOST}$2 [P,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ /index.html`
```

this is main domain sample 301

`Redirect 301 /register www.subdomain.com/register`

Comment: Current loop.
Hit on destinated redirect url -> Main's htaccess -> Sub-> Main's htaccess -> Sub-> Main's htaccess -> Sub-> Infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your redirections on the main htaccess are needed ?

For instance, if you have a file structure like this :

/domainroot
/domainroot/mysub

Instead of doing a redirection in /domainroot, set only the redirection on the htaccess of /domainroot/mysub, like this :
RedirectMatch ^/mysub/(.*)$ http://mysub.domain.com/$1

This will redirect all urls to your subdomain, even for children paths.

Comment: Understood. All the redirect in the domainroot's htaccess is very specific, thus not have a full redirect.

current loop: main -> sub-> sub -> sub-> infinite.

Comment: Can you post an example of a looping url ( and the redirect rules hitted ) ?

Comment: `Redirect 301 /urlofthings http://subdomainwebsite.com/someparam` ->this exists on maindomain's htaccess

Comment: so on the main : "Redirect 301 www.website.com/urlofthings http://subdomain.website.com/someparam" in the main; once redirected to the subdomain, it will not fire anymore the rule of main domain.

Comment: somehow once successfully redirected to the subdomain, the redirection is still happening and looping. Sub -> Sub. Keeps happening

Comment: Can you post here the htaccess rules of the subdomain ?

Comment: Youi have to ensure that index.html is not hitted. Try as last bloc : RewriteBase "/"
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!=/index.html"
RewriteRule "^(.*)" "/index.html

Comment: i tried with `RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html`. on the last line of the subdomain. No effect